# issue on permalink of wp-job manager company profile

Tags: wordpress, plugins

if my company name is wooden house trade the permalink contains non-ASCII character like company/wooden%20housr%20trade%2C%20Inc./?v=8bc2afe7028c. 
I just need these non-ASCII character removed. anyone there to help me with this solution

Comment: change the permalink from the post slug

Comment: I have done that and it doesn't work

Comment: it seems you gave space between "wooden hous" instead of that use "wooden-hous", if you give space, automatically wordpress will convert it to "%20"

Comment: non-ASCII characters are due to the space in a company name, but I am searching for the solution.